# The relationship of the IV fluid Vs body fluid with respect to hypertonic, hypotonic and Isotonic

Tags: intravenous

my nursing lecture isn't responding to my query, so I thought I'd post here...

I'm getting a bit confused how these terms are being explained in the lecture notes and tutorials as there's various worded ways. For example,  there's 4 ways hypertonic is explained...

1. Hypertonic solution = water moves out of cells into blood
2. Hypertonic = higher osmolality than interstitial fluids
3. Hypertonic - Higher osmolarity = fluid is pulled from the cells and the interstitial compartment into the blood vessels
4. Hypertonic (hypernatraemic) dehydration: the solute concentration is above that
   of normal body fluids

What's the best answer if we're asked to explain these terms in the exam?

What is the "solute"? in point 4.

---

Classification of solutions for rehydration

• Hypotonic solution = water moves from blood into cells

• Isotonic solution = no movement

• Hypertonic solution = water moves out of cells into blood

Discuss the three main classification of dehydration, give one example each
a. Hypotonic = Lower osmolality than interstitial fluids e.g 0.45% NaCl
b. Isotonic = same osmolality as intracellular fluids (ICF) e.g. 0.9% NaCl
c. Hypertonic = higher osmolality than interstitial fluids e.g. 10% or 15% dextrose

Isotonic, Hypertonic and Hypotonic Fluids
Isotonic - Same osmolarity as serum = stays where its put and does not affect the size of cells
Hypertonic - Higher osmolarity = fluid is pulled from the cells and the interstitial compartment into the blood vessels
Hypotonic - Lower osmolarity as serum = fluid shifts out of the blood vessels and into the cells and interstitial spaces

IV fluid administration
id v colloid
Sodium chloride 0.9% - isotonic
Dextrose Saline (2½ & ½) commonly (0.9% and 5% dextrose)
Hypotonic – 0.45% saline
Hypertonic – Dextrose 10% or 50%

Classifications of dehydration
• Isotonic dehydration: state in which the solute concentration is practically identical to that of bbody fluids: Na between 130 and 145
• Hypotonic (hyponatraemic) dehydration: the solute concentration is below that of normal body fluids: Na < 130
• Hypertonic (hypernatraemic) dehydration: the solute concentration is above that of normal body fluids: Na > 145

---

So, let me get this clear in my head...

[image]

We put our IV drip into the blood vessel which is where the 0.9NS solution goes. When we talk about dehydration, what part of the diagram above is lacking fluid that the IV solution is trying to replace? Are we trying to rehydrate...

the intravascular fluid?,
the fluid inside the blood cells?,
the interstitial fluid? or
the intracellular fluid?
or a combination of the above?

And... when we talk about "Hyper/Hypo/Isotonic" What are we talking about?

The IV solution
the intravascular fluid?,
the fluid inside the blood cells?,
the interstitial fluid? or
the intracellular fluid?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.